# How to inject a JS script in Qute Template Engine

Tags: quarkus, quarkus-qute

I am using `Quarkus` with the `qute` template engine. I need to inject some dynamic `js` script to load on the HTML page. But `qute` convert `js` like this:

Template file `hello.html`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>redirect by script</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>Hi {name}!</p>
    <script>
        {script}
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Controller

```java
@RequestScoped
public class Resource {
  @Inject
  @Location("hello.html")
  Template hello;

@Route(path = "/s/:name", methods = HttpMethod.GET)
  public Uni<String> rScript(RoutingContext rc) {
    String s = "console.log('Hi from script');";
    return Uni.createFrom().completionStage(() -> hello
            .data("name", rc.request().getParam("name"))
            .data("script", s)
            .renderAsync());
  }
}
```

The template render file like below and script will not run on browser:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>redirect by script</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>NOT_FOUND!</p>
    <script>
        console.log(&#39;test redirect by script&#39;)
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

How can I pass script data to `qute` template file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to turn off [Character Escapes](https://quarkus.io/guides/qute-reference#character-escapes):

Either use `raw`:

```html
    <script>
        {script.raw}
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Or return a `RawString`:

```java
@Route(path = "/s/:name", methods = HttpMethod.GET)
  public Uni<RawString> rScript(RoutingContext rc) {
    String s = "console.log('Hi from script');";
    return Uni.createFrom().completionStage(() -> hello
            .data("name", rc.request().getParam("name"))
            .data("script", new RawString(s))
            .renderAsync());
  }
}
```